# Is there any way to access the data stream (packets) of my internet connection?

Tags: windows, internet-connection

I need to enter that data into a [data stream management system (DSMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_stream_management_system) for accessing the data and applying a bit of data analytics.

Please tell me if I am not clear. I'll explain it more.

**EDIT**

I would *prefer* a method that does not involve any 3rd party apps/plugins/libraries etc. I am willing to get down and dirty with coding it myself. Any words about whether it is not total insanity to go this way will be welcome.

Comment: Capture the packets using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). There's likely a way to pass the data to the DSMS in at least a semi-automated fashion.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty insane to not use an application that already does what you want well. Do you have any reason you don't want to use a 3rd party tool?

Comment: I am basically creating a software, and want it to have as few dependencies as possible.